# PHP Array sorting gives reversed value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to make array sort, but i have a big problem with the final value.
my code is:

```
function bt_sort($a, $b){
if ($a['BestTime'] == $b['BestTime']) return 0;

return $b['BestTime'] < $a['BestTime'] ? 1 : -1;
}

 //....... and where is the sorting:

uasort($info, 'bt_sort');
            if ($bt > -1) {
                foreach ($info as $player2){
                    $bt2 = $player2['BestTime'];
                    $pl2 = $player2['Login'];
                    $ni2 = $player2['NickName'];
                }

                echo $bt2. 'LEGSZARABB:'.$ni2;
```

All ok, but the value what i get is reversed. The value what i would like to see is : `20110`
but i get this value : `01102`

whats wrong?

Comment: Would you like to show us what the array looks like please

Comment: Or amend like this `return $b['BestTime'] < $a['BestTime'] ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Also your `foreach` loop is overwriting the variables so when you come to echo them, you will only see the data from the last occurance of the `$info` array

Comment: Code is incomplete.

Comment: i known its just a slice :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
function bt_sort($a, $b){
    if ($a['BestTime'] == $b['BestTime']) return 0;

    return $b['BestTime'] > $a['BestTime'] ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Note the '>' sign. 
I didn't test it but i think this should sort it from large to small

Comment: i got the correct value, but its printed reversed. example: i need get this: 102030 but i see this :030201

Comment: @Joe you got the same result with the code that I posted?! it can't be.. check yourself again please

Comment: so the original sorting is working, but i get reversed value

Comment: Post an example array please

Comment: example: in my array have 5 value. 1: 102030, 2: 405060, 3: 708090, 4: -1, 5: -1. i need the biggest value. like 708090. the original code found it, but give it reversed, like: 090807 why? :(

Comment: The original code doesnt print the value.. It prints something that I can't understand because there is not enough context.. the code is incomplete.. Try to come up with the smallest example that takes an array and echos a result out. (the wrong result)